# Is there any Ionic code to print barcode on bluetooth printer using ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to print barcode on paper using datecs printer. But Iam not getting correct barcode on paper. I also want to print some kannada letters with barcode.

I tried with different plugins like BTPrinter and datecs from last 1 week. nothing is working

```
window.DatecsPrinter.listBluetoothDevices(
      function (devices) {
        window.DatecsPrinter.connect(devices[0].address,
          function () {
            console.log(devices[0].address),

              window.DatecsPrinter.printText(finalReceipt, 'UTF-8',
                function () {
                  window.DatecsPrinter.setBarcode(3, true, 2, 3, 100);

                  window.DatecsPrinter.printBarcode(
                    75,
                    barcodeData,
                    function () {
                      alert('success!');
                    },
                    function (error) {
                      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    }
                  )
                }, function (error) {
                  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
              );
          },
          function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
          }
        );
      },
      function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not working? For me DatecsPrinter works fine for both printing text, barcode and images.